# how to sort openssl's index.txt based on the time stamp

Tags: arrays, sorting, lua, openssl

I have a need to find specific records within openssl's index.txt file, and then sort them based on the time stamp, so that the latest record appears at the top.  I'm reading the file into an array, and the array looks like this: (i've dumped the table to a log file)

```
database= {}
database[1] = "R    140318001552Z   130318002148Z   7D      unknown /CN=test@test.net/emailAddress=test@test.net"
database[2] = "V    140318001809Z           7E      unknown /CN=test@yahoo.com/emailAddress=test@yahoo.com"
database[3] = "V    140318002157Z           7F      unknown /CN=test@yahoo.com/emailAddress=test@yahoo.com"
```

This I would like to be able to sort this array by the second column, which is the timestamp.  I need the latest record to be sorted first. 
How would I write this code in lua?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pattern is fixed like this, you can simply search for the first number (using `string.match`) and compare those numbers. Note that `string.match` will give you strings not numbers. But since the numbers are of equal length, a lexical comparison should suffice. Of course, you could convert that string to a number or even a date/time object, using an appropriate library, if that's necessary. But let's keep it simple:

```
table.sort(database, function(e1,e2)
    return string.match(e1, "%d+") > string.match(e2, "%d+")
end)
```

The function supplied to `sort` should return `true` if `e1` should come before `e2` in the sorted table.

Comment: would you mind expanding on your answer to include code to do the string.match u mention?  I'm very new to lua.  thanks

Comment: @dot `string.match` is a standard library function. Simply `require "string"` at the beginning of your lua file. See [here](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-string.match) for its documentation and [here](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.4.1) for how patterns work.